# JQuery will work with Fiddler, but not on my server

Tags: javascript, jquery, fiddler

Fiddler Link : http://jsfiddle.net/nLxc4/5/

My code :

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function dynamicSearch() {
    var val = $('#search').val();
    if (val == '') val = '.';
    var srch = new RegExp(val, "gi");

    $('.active').each(function(i, el) {
        if ($(this).text().match(srch)) {
            $(this).show();
        } else {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}

$(':checkbox').bind('change', function() {
    var div = this.value.replace('value', '#div');

    if (this.checked) {
        $(div).addClass('active');
        $(div).show();
    } else {
        $(div).removeClass('active');
        $(div).hide();
    }
});

$('#search').bind('keyup', dynamicSearch);
</script>
</head>

<body>

<form>
    <label for="search">Search:</label>
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search"/>

    <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value1" />value1
    <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value2" />value2
    <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value3" />value3
    <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value4" />value4
    <input type="checkbox" name="modtype" value="value5" />value5
    <div class="row" id="div1" style="display:none">Show Div 1</div>
    <div class="row" id="div2" style="display:none">Show Div 2</div>
    <div class="row" id="div3" style="display:none">Show Div 3</div>
    <div class="row" id="div4" style="display:none">Show Div 4</div>
    <div class="row" id="div5" style="display:none">Show Div 5</div>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

As you can see, in the fiddler, when you click a check box it displays a particular div. On my home server, nothing happens. Can anyone see why this might be the case? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jsfiddler, wraps the js code inside `$(document).ready()` if you choose jQuery as the library. That's why it is working there and not on your server.

Update the following in your code

```
$(document).ready(function() {  //This
$(':checkbox').bind('change', function() {
    var div = this.value.replace('value', '#div');

    if (this.checked) {
        $(div).addClass('active');
        $(div).show();
    } else {
        $(div).removeClass('active');
        $(div).hide();
    }
});

$('#search').bind('keyup', dynamicSearch);
}); //And This
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code:

$(function() {
$(':checkbox').bind('change', function() {
    var div = this.value.replace('value', '#div');

```
if (this.checked) {
    $(div).addClass('active');
    $(div).show();
} else {
    $(div).removeClass('active');
    $(div).hide();
}
```

});

$('#search').bind('keyup', dynamicSearch);
}